# Which of these two approaches is more cache friendly?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I have a set of multiple vectors on which I need to perform exactly the same actions in a `for` loop. And I am not sure what is a better way to do it:

```
for (/*...*/)
{
    std::rotate(/*...*/); // Vec1
    std::rotate(/*...*/); // Vec2
    std::rotate(/*...*/); // Vec3
    std::rotate(/*...*/); // Vec4
    std::rotate(/*...*/); // Vec5
}
```

Or

```
for (/*...*/)
{
    std::rotate(/*...*/); // Vec1
}

for (/*...*/)
{
    std::rotate(/*...*/); // Vec2
}

for (/*...*/)
{
    std::rotate(/*...*/); // Vec3
}

for (/*...*/)
{
    std::rotate(/*...*/); // Vec4
}

for (/*...*/)
{
    std::rotate(/*...*/); // Vec5
}
```

The first example is shorter, and there is only one `for` loop in it, but there are five different objects potentially competing for the same cache being processed in that loop "at the same time".
In the second example there are five `for` loops vs one, but there is only one object being processed in each loop, that [[possibly]] means less cache misses.

Which is more efficient approach? Am I focused on too deep, negligible things?

Comment: *Which is more efficient approach?* - Measure it.

Comment: it also depends upon your particular compiler, and the optimizations you enable at compile time. I don't think you should bother, unless profiling benchmarks tell you that 80% of all computer time is spent in these loops. Some compilers are clever enough to transform your first variant into your second one

Comment: The elephant in the room here, is why is a loop needed at all? If this is an n-place rotate, it can be done more efficiently than iteratively moving one place at a time. If this is a place holder for a different function, the question is hard to reason about.

Comment: @JasonD, in each vector multiple non-contiguous elements should be moved to the beginning one after another, and each element is being moved in each `for` loop iteration.

Comment: @Alexey104 'vector', 'non-contiguous elements', and 'one after another' sound like contradictory statements to me. Either way I strongly suspect that you're optimising the wrong thing.

Comment: @JasonD, sorry, this is my bad English. I mean that I need to choose multiple random elements in each vector and move them to the beginning of this vector. For example, after moving elements 1, 3 and 5 in a vector containing 0-1-2-3-4-5, the result should be 1-3-5-0-2-4. In `for` loop each element is being rotated in one iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Alexey104 remove rotates, use `partition`. That's only one pass through the vector to move everything.

Comment: @harold, Thahk you for the suggestion! `std::partition` is not what I need, because I need to preserve relative order of the elements, but `std::stable_partition` seems to be much better approach than what I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which of these two approaches is more cache friendly?

If a successive iteration operates on elements that are near to those on the previous iteration, then the second approach is potentially cache friendlier.

> Which is more efficient approach?

The one which you can measure to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Both processes depends on your requirements. If your code on both ways result same thing then the first one is definitely efficient and short. If you have different approaches to your codes then the second one is better